# What is the best way to enable dynamic compression programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Assuming the web server is using IIS7+ and dynamic compression is installed I would like the ability to "turn on" compression for specific pages. I want to specifically use the built-in feature in IIS (I know you can write code to look at http headers, etc.).

I know you can turn it on for a specific script in the web.config like this:

```
<location path="Reports/Report.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Suppose I do not want to have to modify the web.config every time I add a new page (or folder) that needs compression. After a google search I found something that seems to work:

```
Request.ServerVariables["IIS_EnableDynamicCompression"] = "1";
```

Because it is not well documented I am concerned that this is perhaps not the best way to do this? Has anyone else used this with success? (So far I have only tested it locally)

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't manage to find a way to turn on the built-in compression you can handle that part of the HTTP protocol yourself. Not trivial but doable. The new open source ASP.NET might have an implementation of it.

Also take a look at `HttpRequest.SetDynamicCompression`. It sets this server variable but in a slightly more elaborate way. I suggest you call this method using reflection.

Comment: Looks like that would work. I am concerned that someone at MS decided not to expose that method for a reason so I am always cautious when using reflection for framework code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the way to go:

```
Request.ServerVariables["IIS_EnableDynamicCompression"] = "1";
```

Based on the fact that it is mentioned on MS engineer
[Thomas Marquardt's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2008/08/27/using-iis-7-0-dynamic-compression-with-asp-net-output-cache.aspx)